# React Native- this.props is null in a scene in a different file

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am a newbie to React Native and was playing with Navigator when I hit this issue.

This is my main class in File A:

```
class SweetSpotClient_Proto extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ test: CategoryScene }}
        renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}/>
    );
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return <CategoryScene test={route.test}/> 
  }
}
```

And this is my Scene in File B:

```
export default class CategoryScene extends Component {
  render() {
    ...
    var testArr = {... } ;
      testArr.forEach(function(testEl) {
    var test = this.props.test;
    });
  }
}
```

For some reason, in **CategoryScene**, **this.props is null** so I cannot access to this.props.test.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I tired the exact same code in my machine, it worked like a charm. Could you double check if it is working or not?

Comment: So I found the issue and my code above was apparently not giving an enough detail. The failing part was wrapped by forEach() block and for some reason (I do not know if this is by design of JS), **within ForEach, the scope is changed to DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope instead of the innermost closure**; thus, this.props becomes null... Thanks all for your help..

Comment: Updated the original posting. I found out that **I was using var instead of let, causing the scope of forEach to be bounded to the outermost object** instead of the nearest enclosing object... Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be sent using passProps.

For example,

`return <CategoryScene test={route.passProps}/>`

check out [Navigating like a Pro](https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.l0noxpa7o)

It helped me a lot in my project.

Comment: From the link you provided:
`Many people use the name passProps, but this can be whatever name you want. passProps just makes sense as it is actually passing properties. `